# Find eigenvalues from a given relation.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

This is a simple problem of linear algebra. One without knowing graph theory may solve it. I am missing a small easy logic.

**Description**: Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and $G^c$ is its complement in the complete graph $K_n$. The Laplacian matrices of $G$ and $G^c$ are given by $L(G)$ and $L(G^c)$. The following relation is well known.
$$L(G) + L(G^c) = L(K_n) = nI_n - J_n$$
$I_n$is identity matrix of order $n$ and $J_n$ is a matrix with all entrees equal to $1$.

Let us assume that the eigenvalues of $L(G)$ are $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \dots \lambda_{n-1} \ge 0$. Here let us assume $G$ is a connected graph then $\lambda_{n-1} > 0$.

**Question**: Prove that the eigenvalues of $L(G^c)$ are $(n - \lambda_{n - 1}, n - \lambda_{n-2} \dots , n - \lambda_1 , 0)$

The eigenvalues of $I_n$ are all $1$. As each element of $J_n$ are $1$, its trace is $n$ and determinant is $0$. So eigenvalues will be $n$ with multiplicity $1$ and $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$. Here I am not getting a small and easy logic to prove the result. **Please Explain**.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is your question? Prove that that those are the eigenvalues of $L(G^c)$ or that the eigenvalues of $J_n$ are $0$ and $n$?

Comment: Eigenvalues of $L(G^c)$.

Comment: Well daw answered the question, but I just wanted to point out that just the fact that $J_n$ has trace $n$ and determinant $0$ does *not* imply those eigenvalues and multiplicities, (as you seem to think from the way you worded the paragraph).

Comment: @Casteels Thank you for pointing out one of my doubts. I get it. $J_n$ is a real symmetric matrix with rank $1$. So all eigenvalues are real and it will have only one non-zero eigenvalue. As trace $J_n$ is $n$, only one eigenvalue will be $n$. Is it?

Comment: Yes that's right. Once you know that $n-1$ eigenvalues are $0$, then the trace has to equal the remaining eigenvalue. Alternatively, you can deduce that $n$ is an eigenvalue by noticing that the all $1$'s vector is an eigenvector of $J_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda_{n-1}>0$ then the eigenspace associated to eigenvalue $\lambda_0=0$ of $L(G)$ consists solely of multiples of $e:=(1,1,\dots,1)^T$. The eigenvectors to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1\dots \lambda_{n-1}$ are thus orthogonal to $e$.

Now take the an eigenvector $v_i$ of $L(G)$ associated to $\lambda_i$, $i\in\{1\dots n-1\}$. Then we obtain
$$
L(G^c)v_i = nv_i - J_nv_i -L(G)v_i = (n-\lambda_i)v_i
$$
since $J_nv_i = 0$ due to $e^Tv_i=0$. Hence, $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $L(G^c)$ as well with corresponding eigenvalue $n-\lambda_i$.

Comment: Nice proof. Many many thanks.